# donnez-moi or me donner? which one to use in this conversation?

Tags: verbes, conjugaison, pronoms-personnels

Can you please explain which one is right and why? I feel both are right.

> pouvez-vous donnez-moi votre position?

ou

> pouvez-vous me donner votre position?

Comment: Using the correct tags helps getting answers because some of those who can answer only watch certain tags. [*ancien-français*](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ancien-fran%c3%a7ais?tab=Active) (Old French) and [français-classique](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/francais-classique) were not relevant here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to build a sentence where *donner* is not used on its own but with ***pouvoir*** that acts here as an auxiliary. The rule is that the verb that *pouvoir* modifies is in the infinitive. So what you want is *pouvoir donner* where only *pouvoir* is conjugated (*je peux donner, tu peux donner, vous pouvez donner* etc.). And so when used for a request you get : ***Pouvez-vous donner* ?**

***Me*** is the indirect object of *donner* and the rule is that it goes before the verb, so we have: ***Pouvez-vous me donner ?***

Of your two proposals only this one is correct:

> **Pouvez-vous me donner votre position ?**

Your other sentence is **not** correct. I expect your confusion comes from the fact that, *donnez-moi* on its own is a valid sentence. But having *pouvoir* modifies the meaning.

- *Pouvez-vous me donner votre position ?* expresses a polite request.
- *Donnez-moi votre position.*  is a command.

---

More information:

- [Modal verbs *vouloir, pouvoir, devoir*](https://laits.utexas.edu/tex/gr/vm1.html)
- [*Pouvoir* – can, to be able](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/pouvoir-lesson/)
- [How do you use indirect object pronouns in French?](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/french-easy-learning/how-do-you-use-indirect-object-pronouns-in-french)

Comment: got it, pouvoir modifies the meaning. Thank you.